# How to add a custom link in a multibranch Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

We are archiving a lot of html reports in a Jenkins pipeline ([scripted Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline)). These are accessible through a link "Last Successful Artifacts" on the job page as usual. But we would like to create an additional custom link that that points to one of these reports (that is being generated whether the build is successful or not).

I found the [DocLink](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/DocLinks+Plugin) plugin, but it's not listed on the [pipeline compatibility list](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) and I'm not able to figure out how this eventually could be used in a pipeline.

The [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) is another one I was looking at. But it’s not suited for our use case, since it requires us to gather all reports and publish them again. It also puts all the content in an iframe, but all we need is link to one of the already archived html reports.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a example to add summary links to a build

```
manager.createSummary("document.png").appendText("<a href='"+ pom.url + "'>View Maven Site</a>", false)
```

As that method accepts HTML and can be used for XSS you need to approve them.
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

for more examples look here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

For pipeline the [Badge plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/badge-plugin) was extracted from the Groovy Postbuild plugin  and if can create the summary using something like:

```
createSummary icon:'package.png', text: "<a href='$pom.url'>View Maven Site</a>"
```